# Reuse table from multiple entities in entity framework core 3.1

Tags: c#, database-design, entity-framework-core, entity, asp.net-core-3.1

I try to create the following database design with **EF Core 3.1** (code-first)

1. Entity "Recipe" can have a list of type "Resource" and a single type of "NutritionFacts"
2. Entity "Ingredient" can have a single "NutritionFacts"
3. Entity "Instruction" can have a list of type "Resource"

But I found no way to implement this without having multiple "NutritionFacts" or "Resource" tables. (RecipeNutritionFacts-/IngredientNutritionFacts)
And I also don't want to blow up my "Recipe" or "Ingredient" tables with the columns from the "NutritionFacts-/Resource" entities. (owned types)

Goal: I would like to reuse the tables "Resource" and "NutritionFacts" in multiple entities.

If I delete a "Resource" from the collection in entity "Recipe" or "Instrucion" then the corresponding "Resource" entity should be also deleted. (`recipe.Resource.remove(x)`)
Same for a "NutritionFacts" from entity "Recipe" or "Ingredient" (`recipe.NutritionFacts = null`)

I already tried several combinations with owned types, etc... but with no success.
Any ideas for a good implementation to reach this goal?

**Example Classes:**

```
public class NutritionFacts
{
    public int NutritionFactsId { get; set; }
    public decimal Kcal { get; set; }
    public decimal Fat { get; set; }
}

public class Resource
{
    public int ResourceId { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
}

public class Ingredient
{
    public int IngredientId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual NutritionFacts NutritionFacts { get; set; }
}

public class Recipe
{
    public int RecipeId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual NutritionFacts NutritionFacts { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Resource> Resources { get; set; }
}

public class Instruction
{
    public int InstructionId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Resource> Resources { get; set; }
}
```

**Example Context:**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        // variant-1 owned
        modelBuilder.Entity<Ingredient>().OwnsOne(x => x.NutritionFacts).HasKey(r => r.UniqueIdentifier);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Entities.Recipe>().OwnsOne(x => x.NutritionFacts).HasKey(r => r.UniqueIdentifier);

        // variant-2
        modelBuilder.Entity<Entities.Recipe>()
            .HasOne(p => p.NutritionFacts).WithOne();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Ingredient>()
            .HasOne(p => p.NutritionFacts).WithOne();
    }
```

Comment: Can you share your `OnModelCreating` function (in your db context class)? As your entities don't have any `[attributes]` maybe you are fluently adding the relationships?

Comment: I added an example. But I tried such a lot of things and combinations during the last days and played with [attributes] and fluent api so that I am not sure if this was a complete working state.

Comment: @Simon Did you make it work?

Comment: @Yurii sorry for my late reply. Unfortunately not but didn't had much time to investigate into this. At the moment I would go with separate tables instead of reusing table. If you find a better solution then I would appreciate if you could share it with me.